# How to round 65.494 --> 65, but 65.495 --> 66

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

**Update**

Hi all, thanks for your input. I read them all, they are useful.

Well, the first idea was to round from the last decimal digit until getting final integer, like this:

```
65.494 -> 65.49 -> 65.5 -> 66
65.449 -> 65.45 -> 65.5 -> 66
65.4444449 -> 65.444445 -> 65.44445 -> 65.4445 -> 65.445 -> 65.45 -> 65.5 -> 66
```

However, after simulate more data given by user, I figured out that user actually use Excel to format data to #,##0.00. Then round again to get final integer from that 2 digits present on screen rather than referencing to the cell value.

So, I ended up calling Math.Round 2 times to simulate what user does in Excel. Not a beautiful code, but I hope it works as expected. That's it.

```
65.495 -> 66
Math.Round(Math.Round(65.495, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

65.49445 -> 65
Math.Round(Math.Round(65.49445, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

---

**Original post**

I have a rounding issue for specific set of numbers. User expects system to starting rounding from the last decimal place and continue rounding until final integer number without decimal. The rounding concept is away from zero (if greater or equal 5, round up).

What I tried and success are show above, but it's not a proper way to do it since Math.Round must be called many times based on number of decimal place. Kindly suggest a proper way to achieve this, thank you.

**Example #1:**

```
65.494 --> 65
Math.Round(Math.Round(65.494,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

65.495 --> 66
Math.Round(Math.Round(65.495,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

**Example #2:**

```
65.4944 --> 65
Math.Round(Math.Round(Math.Round(65.4944,3,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

65.4945 --> 66
Math.Round(Math.Round(Math.Round(65.4945,3,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: "Not a proper way", unfortunately there is no implementation of your rounding method in .NET, so you'll either have to call Math.Round multiple times, or come up with your own implementation.

Comment: 65.494 -> 65.49 -> 65.5 -> 66 so how did you get to 65?

Comment: In any case, what I would do if I were you were to write an implementation in a class, and then write extensive unit tests for it. Even if you end up with what you might think of as an "iffy" implementation right now, as long as it does what you want, at least you have an implementation. Then, when you find or can think of better alternatives, you also have all the unit-tests to verify that your new implementation follows the same rules.

Comment: For instance, what would 65.449 round to, or 65.4444449?

Comment: @AndrewMorton based on above implementation, it looks like they don't round to one decimal, it's two straight to zero

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Lasse commented earlier (since deleted) that until the OP can provide an actual method for the rounding, we can't tell. Perhaps it is a numerology thing; we can only speculate.

Comment: I seriously doubt you will find any shortcut for these strange rounding rules, so you are probably stuck with some comparison of `value % 1`

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, you're right. It should be rounded like that. I mistakenly skip rounding to 1 digit before going to 0 digit.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for your input. Also, I use your number to explain more detail in the update above.

Comment: @user10268539 You might want to explain to the user that there is a problem with their method, especially if auditors might ever go over the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round using *custom rule*

```
0.(49) = 0.49494949... => 0
0.(49) + epsilon       => 1 // epsilon is infinitesimal value
```

you can try

**Code:**

```
  private static double MyRound(double value) =>
     Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.ToZero) + 
    (int)Math.Clamp((value % 1) * 99 / 49, -1, 1);
```

**Demo:**

```
  double[] tests = new double[] {
     65.494,
     65.495,
    -65.494,
    -65.495,
     65.0,
     65.5,
     65.999, 
    -65.999,
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,8} => {MyRound(test),3}"));

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  65.494 =>  65
  65.495 =>  66
 -65.494 => -65
 -65.495 => -66
      65 =>  65
    65.5 =>  66
  65.999 =>  66
 -65.999 => -66
```

**Edit:** If custom rule is

```
0.(4) = 0.44444444... => 0
0.(4) + epsilon       => 1 // epsilon is infinitesimal value
```

You can exploit the same idea but with different coefficent: `9 / 4` instead of `99 / 49`

```
private static double MyRound(double value) =>
  Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.ToZero) + 
  (int)Math.Clamp((value % 1) * 9 / 4, -1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will consider writing extenstion or custom rule based on your example.